# tracking bash calls

Tags: python, linux, bash, scripting

I'd like a script/tool like understand C++(scitools) that give backtraces for a master bash script that call :

- other bash scripts
- Python
- Java
- Perl

to let me know what happend.

I don't need sophisticated graph, a simple text file is suficient.

What can let me do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use *strace* to track your script's execution of other scripts or programs.

You will have to run your script like: *strace -q -f -e execve yourscript.sh*.

This will trace all calls made to other executables.

```
[root@devel ~]# ./x.sh 
x
y
z
[root@devel ~]# cat x.sh 
#!/bin/bash
echo x
./y.sh

[root@devel ~]# cat y.sh 
#!/bin/bash

echo y
./z.sh
[root@devel ~]# cat z.sh 
#!/bin/bash

echo z

[root@devel ~]# strace -q -f -e execve ./x.sh 
execve("./x.sh", ["./x.sh"], [/* 28 vars */]) = 0
x
[pid 19781] execve("./y.sh", ["./y.sh"], [/* 28 vars */]) = 0
y
[pid 19782] execve("./z.sh", ["./z.sh"], [/* 28 vars */]) = 0
z
[pid 19781] --- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) —
```

It will trace even calls to perl or other executables.

```
[root@devel ~]# cat x.sh 
#!/bin/bash
echo x
./y.sh
ls >/dev/null 2>&1
[root@devel ~]# cat y.sh 
#!/bin/bash

echo y
perl -e 'print "z\n";'
[root@devel ~]# ./x.sh 
x
y
z
[root@devel ~]# strace -q -f -e execve ./x.sh 
execve("./x.sh", ["./x.sh"], [/* 28 vars */]) = 0
x
[pid 20300] execve("./y.sh", ["./y.sh"], [/* 28 vars */]) = 0
y
[pid 20301] execve("/usr/bin/perl", ["perl", "-e", "print \"z\\n\";"], [/* 28 vars */]) = 0
z
[pid 20300] --- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
[pid 20302] execve("/bin/ls", ["ls"], [/* 28 vars */]) = 0
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
[root@devel ~]#
```

Comment: very good, simple and usefull. Thus I need to implement a bash script to call the master one with the strace and pipe it to file instead of stdout ?

Comment: If you always need the trace (even in production) you could write a wrapper script that executes the strace and captures only stderr in a log file (strace -q -f -e execve ./x.sh 2>/var/log/x.trace). This way you will have the normal output on stdout and the trace in /var/log/x.trace. The only problem with this is that if your script writes to stderr, that will also end up in x.trace.

Answer (score 6):

Using `set -x` or running the script using `bash -x` will print every line before it's executed (but after variable substitution, which can be useful, but can also be nasty, sometimes):

```
bash -x myScript.sh
```

Comment: well this is not exactly that as this is a printout of the bash. in case of multiple calls (bash call bash ) I have to do it manually. As it's a master script, too many things are printed out; as you said (@Joachim) this is nasty.

Comment: It should be `set -x` rather than `+x`. Adding `-v` will print the line without expansion.

Comment: @Dennis: thanks, fixed. I usually use the `bash -x` version, so I didn't remember correctly.

Comment: `+x` turns off `xtrace` in either case.

Answer (score 0):

If you just neeed bash scripts call log, use this app
https://github.com/lvitya/bash_wrapper

bash_wrapper replaces the bash itself, logs who called bash_wrapper and exec the original bash. That is it deals with nested bash calls independently from `-x` option.

You can modify the source code to obtain call graph using GraphViz's dot format.